# Flutter - Trying to achieve this complex layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, clipper

I am trying to achieve the following Flutter layout ( as shown in the picture).

[image]

I want to place two images side by side which I know can be achieved easily using Row but what I want is to separate the two images by the shape ( as shown in the picture). Also, I am aware of using CustomClipper but I am not able to think of a way to achieve so.

I will be so grateful if somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stack` for part I with 3 children in this order:
- a container for your thunderbolt (or any path you like) color
- a first image for Area I
- a second image for Area II

Wrap each image into a `ClipPath` with a a specific `CustomClipper<Path>`: the goal is to clip the image to the side on which it should be displayed **with** a "padding" with the other clipper. In the middle, you will have a zone where no image is clipped, so the first widget in the stack will be displayed.

Here is the complete source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: ComplexLayoutApp()),
    ),
  );
}

class ComplexLayoutApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Expanded(child: Part1()),
      Expanded(child: Part2()),
    ]);
  }
}

class Part1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
      ClipPath(
        clipper: Area1CustomClipper(),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/seed/area1/400/100',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          )),
      ClipPath(
          clipper: Area2CustomClipper(),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ))
    ]);
  }
}

class Part2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: Text("Part II")),
      ],
    );
  }
}

const double offset = 0.34;

class Area1CustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(4*size.width/8, 0);
    path.lineTo((4-offset)*size.width/8, (4)*size.height/8);
    path.lineTo((4)*size.width/8, (4)*size.height/8);
    path.lineTo(size.width/2, size.height);

    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class Area2CustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(4*size.width/8, 0);
    path.lineTo((4)*size.width/8, (4-offset)*size.height/8);
    path.lineTo((4+offset)*size.width/8, (4 - offset)*size.height/8);
    path.lineTo(size.width/2, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

And it produces the following UI:
[image]

Comment: A great thanks to you, sir. You have done a wonderful job. I highly appreciate and respect that. I am happy with the solution you have provided and I will even use it. But, I was wondering if I can achieve same layout as I have drawn in the picture of my question. Is this possible? Thank you. <3

Comment: What is the difference between my solution and the layout you've drawn?

Comment: Please see this image for the difference in the output https://i.imgur.com/MO3CU1N.jpg

Comment: Ok :-D change the path of each clipper for your need

Comment: hmm, yes :P I am trying to figure out the paths :p Well if you know, please tell me. Thank you <3